# p:selectBooleanButton doesn't render preselected value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I been reading / trying examples for hours, and I can't make it work. I'm using Primefaces 4.0

I just need a way to select/unselect and assign those values to a Map

The xhtml looks like this.

```
<p:selectBooleanButton value="#{presupuestoBean.itemsCambiar[itemPresupuesto.id]}"
onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">
     <p:ajax listener="#{presupuestoBean.updateItemPresupuestoAsignado(itemPresupuesto.id,0)}"/>
</p:selectBooleanButton>
```

Init Method (reset to False just in case, and then assign the true values)

```
 for (ItemPresupuesto itemsPresupuestoDefault : itemsPresupuestoDefaults) {
        itemsCambiar.put(itemsPresupuestoDefault.getId(),Boolean.FALSE);
    }
```

assign TRUE values

```
if (itemPresupuestoAsignado.isCambiar()) {
            itemsCambiar.put(itemPresupuestoAsignado.getId(), Boolean.TRUE);

        }
```

and

```
public Map<Long, Boolean> getItemsCambiar() {
        return itemsCambiar;
    }
```

My expected behavior is when the itemsCambiar has some item 'TRUE', the onIcon should be displayed. But it's not happening, all p:selectBooleanButton  are displaying as offIcon.

I notice a couple of things while debugging.

- The Boolean value assigned at Init, is properly assigned.
- If I change the selectBooleanButton for an outputLabel, is showing 'true' (which is correct)
- When I change the selectBooleanButton, and the event is fired, I can see that the 'true' value in the HashMap is not a java.lang.Boolean but a java.lang.String (attachment)

So maybe, this problem is related a cast problem, but I'm putting Boolean.TRUE in the map, so ... 
any ideas?

[image]

Comment: @BalusC I'm not following you maybe because of the property name. The map property is 'itemsCambiar', and it's a <Long,Boolean> hashmap. ItemPresupuesto doesn't have a boolean property 'cambiar'

Comment: @BalusC, I have fixed the issue. However I'm not so happy with the solution, and I notice that you're kind of an expert in JSF, could you please check my own answer link. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Finally I fixed changing ui:repeat to h:datatable, (I don't know why is working).

I have created another question to request some help about it [ui:repeat vs h:datatable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598827/uirepeat-vs-hdatatable-behavior)

Thanks,