# JSF 2 ui:repeat vs h:datatable behavior

Tags: jsf-2

I had a bad time trying to solve [p:selectBooleanButton doesn't render preselected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576218/pselectbooleanbutton-doesnt-render-preselected-value), a lot of hours just to fix it changing ui:repeat to h:datatable.

Here is both pieces of code.

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{presupuestoBean.getItemsPresupuestBySeccion('Parte Delantera')}" var="itemPresupuesto">
    <tr>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{itemPresupuesto.descripcion}"/></td>
        <td>
            <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{presupuestoBean.itemsPresupuestoAsignadoCambiar[itemPresupuesto.id]}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{presupuestoBean.itemsPresupuestoAsignadoCambiar[itemPresupuesto.id]}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

[image: UI repeat output]

(Notice that the button is showing 'FALSE (or NO)' value although the property value is 'TRUE' as displayed by outputText)

On the other hand, the exactly same code with h:datatable.

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{presupuestoBean.getItemsPresupuestBySeccion('Parte Delantera')}" var="itemPresupuesto2">
    <h:column>
         <h:outputText value="#{itemPresupuesto2.descripcion}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{presupuestoBean.itemsPresupuestoAsignadoCambiar[itemPresupuesto2.id]}" onLabel="Si" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{presupuestoBean.itemsPresupuestoAsignadoCambiar[itemPresupuesto2.id]}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

[image: Datatable Ouput]

Anyone know why is this happening ??. As far as I know, this two tags could be exchangeable. (at least according the example that I saw e.g [JSF 2 Repeat Tag Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-repeat-tag-example/))

I'm using com.sun.faces jsf-api and jsf-impl 2.2.4
Also Primefaces 4.0

Comment: `#presupuestoBean.itemsPresupuestoAsignadoCambiar[itemPresupuesto.id]}}` is invalid syntax, is it only a copy mistake?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, yes. Was just a copy mistake. Thanks! (I've edited my answer)

Comment: Well verify again there are `{` missing right after `#`.

Comment: You don't tell us your jsf-primefaces versions. Apart from that, you should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to make your code copy-paste and runnable.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie thanks! I fixed the code. I had problems trying to copy paste the code into the stackoverflow editor.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I've updated the question. the version is 4.0 and jsf-api 2.2.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior, and was not able to make work the ui:repeat properly with map and default value.
As you are using primefaces, you might also found **p:dataGrid** as an alternative to h:dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse **view build time** with **view render time**! BalusC posted an explanation here:

[JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)